# SQL gets error when running a select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran this query:

```
Select * from users where user_id=20;
```

and got this error:

```
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 37
```

I want to know why this happened and the correct query for this.

Answer (score 2):

You have [created your table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e9804307f1c529d87c6dcfe882b92dd) with `user_id` defined as a `long` data type. Unlike C/Java/etc., `long` is not a numeric type [in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F):

> `LONG` columns store variable-length character strings containing up to 2 gigabytes -1, or 231-1 bytes. `LONG` columns have many of the characteristics of `VARCHAR2` columns. You can use `LONG` columns to store long text strings.

You are getting the error when Oracle tries to implicitly convert the string value to a number to compare with the number 20. While that would work with a `varchar2` column, the `long` data type has a lot of restrictions - and shouldn't be used even for long strings, which should be CLOBs.

If your column holds numeric values then it [should be declared](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3cc0badb0b0ed8ddde243a5fa78fb83) as `number`, and for an ID column probably as `number(38)` to make it an integer.